# 8086 Assembly Int 21h and Extended ASCII characters

Tags: assembly, ascii, dos, x86-16, codepages

I need some help with an assignment. I need to process a plain text file in ASCII and return how many characters of each code are present (how many a's, how many b's, and so on). It works now almost perfectly.

I now have the problem that, if there is an extended ASCII character on the file, when I use the 3fh service interruption, it doesn't read them well.

For example, if the file has an é (ascii code 130), it reads an ß (ascii code 225). I'm afraid I'm using the interrupt wrong, but I wouldn't know what to do, so a little help here would be greatly appreciated. Debugging also doesn't help, because the interrupt is executed well without errors, it just returns with the wrong values in the buffer.

This is the exact code I'm using to read the file. I have the handle from a previous interrupt.

```
      xor ax,ax
      lea dx, buffer        
      mov ah,3fh            
      mov bx,handle         
      mov cx,4096           
      int 21h
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I found the problem, but no idea how to solve it. Turns out that the character read as a 225 it's not é, but á. The code for á should be 160 according to every ASCII table i've found... but it's 225 in Unicode... Which is weird, since I'm specifically telling Notepad to save it as ANSI, not ASCII...

Comment: You are using MS-DOS? Wow are you from the past?

Comment: Anything above 127 isn't ASCII....

Comment: @Michael-O yep, it's an Assembly course.

Comment: @dda I know, it's extended ASCII, for characters of languages other than english. But still, if I enter manually ALT+130 for a 21/08h interrupt, it recognizes the é.

Comment: Function 3fh does not do any interpretation or processing of file data. If there's 130, you should get 130, if there's 225, you should get 225.

Comment: How do you know if the file does not contain char 225, but 130 instead? Could you be saving that file in a different code page / encoding?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Then maybe I'm saving the text file wrong... I'm using good old windows notepad, and saving it in ANSI format. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @ssg I know it has 130 because I used ALT+130 to write it. Although I may very possibly be wrong, because I admit I know next to nothing about code page / encoding. All I know is that I'm using Notepad and saving it as ANSI encoding.

Comment: Either stick to ASCII (find a list of ASCII chars/codes) or use known encodings (perhaps even UTF8) or do not try to interpret character codes, just count different chars/codes as you're only asked to count them.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I feel very tempted to do as you say and just count them, even if the program prints ß instead of é... However, the teacher demanded that we show the correct character. I'm using the table I found in [link](http://www.asciitable.com/) and several other sites, and as I said, when I enter the character through any other interrupt it detects it correctly...

Comment: @dhcarmona use an editor like Notepad2: http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html - it allows you to select text encoding to save and pick any encoding you want until you get the right code for that character. your code looks good. and check that article out: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I edited the question with something I found...

Comment: You are mixing two encodings. MS-DOS uses code page 437 (where é is code 130) but Notepad in ANSI mode uses code page 1252 (where é is code 233).

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh, I see... Yeah, I just followed ssg's suggestion and used Notepad2 to save the file in DOS-OEM encoding. Now it works with my assembly program, but I can't see the text on Windows. It seems that I can't get both, but I feel better now that I know what's going on. Thanks a lot to you all!!

Comment: If you want the text to be visible in Windows, then you have to use a Windows code page. It's like saying "chat" to somebody who speaks French, so they think you're talking about a cat. If you want them to understand you, you need to speak French.

Comment: @RaymondChen You should probably make the answer based on the comments.

Comment: @dhcarmona, where is the connection between DOS and assembly? There is none. ASM existed way before DOS.

Comment: @dhcarmona No such thing as "extended ASCII". Anything with a codepoint above 127 is **not** ASCII.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing code pages.

MS-DOS uses code page 437, where é is code 130. But Notepad in ANSI mode uses [code page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), where é is code 233.

ASCII is defined only up to 127, so there is no such thing as an ASCII chart for 130 or 160. Extended ASCII is not standardized, so different people extend it in different ways. In particular, MS-DOS and Windows use different code pages which are effectively different extended ASCII tables.

If you're going to be using MS-DOS to manipulate your file, then use code page 437. If you're going to be using Windows to manipulate your file, then use code page 1252. (Or better, use Unicode.)

But you cannot get a file to be interpreted the same in both MS-DOS and Windows, in the same way you cannot write a book that can be interpreted the same in both English and French.

Comment: Can you please show how to do that? How can I choose what code page to use programmatically? (specifically for box-drawing characters)

Comment: If you want to write a `é` for an MS-DOS program, write 130. If you want to write a `é` for a Windows program, use 233. That action (deciding whether to write 130 or 233) is "choosing a code page". Code page 1252 does not have box drawing characters.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I actually tell my program to use that page?

Comment: If you want code page 437, then write a 130 when you need a `é`. Put the number 130 in your buffer and write it. This isn't something you "tell" the program. It's just something you do. It's like asking "How do I tell my program to print messages in French?" You just do it. Put a French message in the buffer and print it.

Comment: Oh. I get it. Thank you so much!