# Printing special (non-Latin) characters in a legacy-BIOS bootloader

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, codepages

I'm making a simple bootloader. I want to print some non-latin text on the screen but it can't print the character 'ü' correctly. How can I make my OS print characters like `ü`? I've searched for it but I couldn't find anything about it.

main.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]

call clear
mov bx, SELAM
call print
call print_nl
mov bx, NABER
call print

jmp $

%include "print.asm"

SELAM:
    db 'Selamun Aleyküm.', 0
NABER:
    db 'Nabün?', 0

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

print.asm

```
print:
    pusha

start:
    mov al, [bx]
    cmp al, 0 
    je done

    mov ah, 0x0e
    int 0x10
    
    add bx, 1
    jmp start

done:
    popa
    ret



print_nl:
    pusha
    
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x0a
    int 0x10
    mov al, 0x0d
    int 0x10
    
    popa
    ret

clear:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x00
    mov al, 0x03
    int 0x10
    popa
    ret
```

And I use NASM as Assembler.

Comment: Related: [How to get alpha character (α) in DOS/Asembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67658842) mentions changing codepages, but only via DOS calls, thus not available in a bootloader.  Also semi-related: [8086 Assembly Int 21h and Extended ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12326609) re: editors for source code using a different character set, if you try to use special characters literally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The editor that you use to write the source text might not map the ASCII code for the character "ü" to the number 129. But the computer that executes your bootloader will be using codepage 437 (at startup), and thus require 129 to display "ü".

You can manually insert the correct ASCII code in the text like so:

```
SELAM:
    db 'Selamun Aleyk', 129, 'm.', 0
NABER:
    db 'Nab', 129, 'n?', 0
```

There's also an uppercase version "Ü":

```
SELAM:
    db 'SELAMUN ALEYK', 154, 'M.', 0
NABER:
    db 'NAB', 154, 'N?', 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just about all IBM compatible computers use code page 437 for generating text, you'd have to manually create some sort of lookup table I guess.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Comment: On Linux you can use `echo äöü | iconv -t 437 | hd` for this purpose.